# Solving for a cubic polynomial's roots using Viete's Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, cubics

I am asked to find the roots $f(x)=x^3-24x^2-24x-25$. However, the only thing I am aware of in regards to finding the roots of cubic polynomials is Viete's Theorem. However, this theorem requires that the polynomial be in the form $f(x)=x^3+qx+r$ i.e. without the quadratic element. Am I missing how Viete can be used to answer this question?

Comment: Vieta is somewhat complicated for polynomials of degree $3$. The sum of the roots must be $24$ , the product $25$ and if the roots are $a,b$ and $c$, the value of $ab+ac+bc$ must be $-24$.

Comment: Try the rational root theorem.

Comment: In this case, Vieta fails because we only have one real root, namely $25$. The other (complex) roots multiply to $1$.

Comment: When there is only one real root, Cardano-Tartaglia's method works.

Comment: They were very careful to pick coefficients so that, if you guessed the root $25,$ you could confirm it on paper without error; or, in your head, as there is a clear pattern. All you need is to notice is that $25 - 24 = 1$

Comment: In fact, generically, $$ (x \ - \ r) · (x^2 \ + \ x  \ + \ 1 ) \ \ = \ \ x^3 \ - \ (r-1)  x^2 \ - \ (r-1) x \ - \ r \ \ . $$  The coefficients are indeed suspicious.

Answer (score 1):

In order to set the quadratic coefficient with zero, replace $x$ with $x+8$.  This will shift all of the roots by 8 and the resulting polynomial (once you expand out the powers of $x+8$) will be of the desired form.

In general, to convert a cubic of form $x^3 + ax^2+bx+c$ to one of form $x^3 + qx + r$, you replace $x$ with $x-a/3$.

E: For this example in specific, it might be more effective to first look for rational roots, as mentioned by lhf above in comments.  While careful use of the cubic formula will give you a real root, it might be in an ugly form that's not obvious how to simplify.